# alert(): cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript, auth0

Preface: I've look at questions similar to this error but haven't found anything useful.

What exactly is wrong with this code? I'm getting an error at the line that reads `error => alert(error.json().message)`:

```
    this.authHttp
        .patch('https://' + myConfig.domain + '/api/v2/users/' + this.auth.userProfile.user_id, data, {headers: headers})
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                this.auth.userProfile = response;
                localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            error => alert(error.json().message)
        );
```

Heres my data and header objects used for the first one:

```
    var alert = new Alert;
    alert.name = this.name;
    // etc....

    var headers: any = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    var data: any = JSON.stringify({
        user_metadata: {
            alerts: [alert]
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try to figure out what is different between the two files that can cause this. Maybe you are including something that adds signatures to `alert`? Also, why do you have the same exact code twice?

Comment: @nitzan because the `data` is different in the other code, these statements appear in different files. Good idea on checking includes, I'll check that

Comment: Oh Jesus, it's because the object I put into `data` is **called** alert. If you wanna post an answer saying I have changed the signature of alert I'll accept it, I'm editing my post so you see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

<sub>For greater visibility including the hint from user **Nitzan Tomer** as a community wiki answer.</sub>

The root cause was adding additional code that changed the signatures for `alert`.

In this particular case, adding a variable named `alert` made it throw an error when later trying to call the `alert` as a function.